# For each for these numbers make a loop on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

From a mySQL row I get the below from column `coop` as appeared (with commas)

```
1,2,6,27
```

My question is how can I have something like

```
for
```

*as numbers as the column*

```
do the loop {
{
```

Comment: Please post the code you already have

Comment: `explode()` function, may be?

Comment: `foreach(explode(',', $coop) as $number) { }`

Comment: looks like you should normalize your data in the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the values stored in a string, let's call it `$dbValue`, you can split that string into an array:

```
$values = explode(",", $dbValue);
```

Then just loop over that array:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    // do something with each value
}
```

As an aside... Storing delimited values in a single database field is *very often* a bad idea.  Each database field should contain one discrete value.  If multiple values are needed, you'd create a separate table with a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: This is a functional answer.

Comment: @AndrewCoder damned by faint praise

Comment: My comment was accurate.  I've learned not to swing too far towards praise or the opposite on this site as many people will just find something to say is wrong, or whatever.  :)

Answer (score 3):

seems foreach

```
$tmp = explode(',', $yourvalue)   // $yourvalue  = '1,2,6,27'
foreach ( $tmp as $key => $value ) {

   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: coop is a string not an array

Comment: @Dagon have update the answer why downvote.. ?

Comment: not my down vote, ill balance it with an up.

Comment: @Dagon thanks   .. this answer is a race..

Comment: The question is poorly asked shows no research, i wouldn't lower my self to *answer* personally :-0